# Displaying a subset of Species in RDA plot in R based on variance explained

Tags: r, plot, vegan, rda

I've run an redundancy analysis on fish assemblage data using the `rda()` function from the `vegan` package in R. I'd like to only add species to the plot which had >10% of variance explained by the analysis.

I have found a reference to doing that [here](http://www.umass.edu/landeco/teaching/multivariate/schedule/constrained2.pdf) on slide 11, but I haven't been able find code anywhere to be able to plot a subset like that.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should post some data...

Comment: Give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451#5965451) so others can paste your code in their R session.

Comment: The `points` and `text` commands for `rda` in **vegan** have a `select` argument that can be used like the name indicates: select a subset for which a condition is true. Then there are commands like `goodness` that can return -- like the name indicates -- goodness-of-fit statistics. Combining these two can get you something like `plot(uh, type="n", dis="sp")` followed with `text(uh, dis="sp", select=goodness(uh, prop=T, summarize=T) > 0.2)`.

Comment: The link that @PaulRougieux posted has some great suggestions on how to do this typically posting the results of `dput()` is a pretty good method. If you're working with a large dataset you should try and post a subset of data which is enough to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @JariOksanen: Thanks a lot. That worked well.

Comment: @AdamMccurdy, Thank you for your helping me improve my question. I'll add the code and data to improve the question for others when I get a chance.

Comment: @PaulRougieux, Thanks to you too for that very useful link

Comment: No problem when you add some data and code you should probably add the solution you came up with based on Jari's suggestion as an answer and accept it to close out the question.